# Mapping ‘space + character’ into ‘non-breaking space + character’

Tags: spacing, xetex, fontspec, unicode, mapping

I have files containing fragments of Old English texts. These files use the letter [wynn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wynn) (ƿ (`U+01BF`) and Ƿ (`U+01F7`)) which I want to print as modern w (`U+0077`) and W (`U+0057`). This I have no problem doing using the a mapping file, which I’ve compiled using `teckit_compile` into `.tec` file (`teckit_compile oldenglish.map -o oldenglish.tec`). I also want the sequence ‘ ·’ (space (`U+0020`) followed by an [interpunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct)) to be mapped into ‘ ·’ ([non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (`U+00A0`) followed by an interpunct), but this for some reason do not work.

This is my `.map` file (`oldenglish.map`):

```
LHSName "old"
RHSName "new"

pass(Unicode)

U+01BF <> U+0077 ; ‘ƿ’→‘w’
U+01F7 <> U+0057 ; ‘Ƿ’→‘W’
U+0020 U+00B7 <> U+00A0 U+00B7 ; ‘ ·’→‘ ·’
```

And this is an example LaTeX file and it’s output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=oldenglish]{Junicode}

\begin{document}
abcwxyz · ABCWXYZ

abcƿxyz · ABCǷXYZ
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the previous code]

I know `U+0020 U+00B7` isn’t being replaced by `U+00A0 U+00B7` because when I test it with `U+0020 U+00B7 <> U+00A0 U+0078` in the last line I don’t get ‘abcwxyz x ABCWXYZ’ but ‘abcwxyz · ABCWXYZ’.

I guess it’s the space (`U+0020`) that causes this problem. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you very much! ☺

Comment: I don't think this can work, because XeTeX never uses the space character. The substitutions with the mapping file are performed when the box is being built and XeTeX has already transformed spaces into space tokens, which insert a skip, not a character.

Comment: @egreg: So the only solution would be manually replacing ‘ ·’ (`U+0020`) with ‘ ·’ (`U+00A0`) or ‘~·’ using my text editor or a program like `sed`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mapping substitutions work on a character basis, but XeTeX never uses the space character; rather, it changes space tokens into horizontal glue, so when the substitution stage is reached, there's never a combination `U+0020 U+00B7`.

You can use `newunicodechar` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=oldenglish]{Junicode}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{·}{\ifhmode\ifdim\lastskip>0pt \unskip~\fi\fi·}

\begin{document}

abcwxyz · ABCWXYZ

abcƿxyz · ABCǷXYZ

\parbox{0pt}{
abcwxyz · ABCWXYZ

abcƿxyz · ABCǷXYZ
}
\end{document}
```

The interpunct character is made active; if it's found in horizontal mode and it's preceded by a space, it removes the space and inserts a nonbreaking space `~`, then it prints itself.

I wouldn't use `U+00A0`, because this is a glyph and so doesn't participate to space stretching or shrinking on a line.

[image]

This assumes that · (U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT) is used only in this context. Something like `\hspace{10pt}·` would remove the space as well.