# XeLaTeX French guillemets non-breaking space best practice

Tags: xetex, pdftex, fontspec, babel, csquotes

What is the best approach to get a non-breaking space just before the closing French guillemet `»` ?

I wish to be able to type in the natural style, which in French is `« bonjour »` with non-breaking spaces before `»` and after `«`. It would be great if the code were clever enough to forgive my occasional use of the English-style `«bonjour»` and add the forgotten space for me. Now I get this:

[image]

I am using the `babel` package with the `[french]` option. I am also using the `csquotes` package with the `[babel]` option. I have also included the `xspace` package in the belief/hope that it would help with the spaces. I am  not committed to these packages or options, although I believe they are common. I am open to using the `panglossia` package, which is also quite popular to typeset foreign languages, if that would help. For this particular project, I am committed to using `XeLaTeX`, but the problem also exists when I compile with `PDFLaTeX`. I am compiling a French text with `UTF-8` encoding enabled. Is there anything I am overlooking here? Do I need to redefine `guillemets` commands? I have seen several ways to do this, but as they did not seem to work I am leaving them out of my **MWE** so as not to have misleading, deprecated code around.

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=14cm,paperheight=20.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}% use this font and geometry width to reproduce bad break
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern} 
\fi
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

Je n'ai rien à dire --- mais je le dis bien : je suis un « beau parleur ».

Je n'ai rien à dire -- mais je le dis bien: je suis un «beau parleur».

Je n'ai rien à dire :  je suis un «  beau parleur  » .

Je n'ai rien à dire:je suis un «beau parleur» .

\end{document}
```

**Edit** I have been explicit about the requirement that I use the guillemets directly and not a shortcut like `\fg` or `\og`. This is because I co-write with someone who will be typing in a standard text processor (and I will be copy-pasting their text back and forth several times).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217943/mapping-space-character-into-non-breaking-space-character?rq=1

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71035/wrong-spacing-around-guillemets

Comment: The bug must have been fixed in 2019: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/143#issuecomment-524016634.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `babel`, you have to use `\frenchbsetup{og=«, fg=»}`. For `polyglossia`, you have nothing to do, except that the package inserts a breakable space (bug?), so in case the space does break, you have to insert an unbreakable thin space by hand (`\,`).

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=14cm,paperheight=20.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}% use this font and geometry width to reproduce bad break
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{og=«, fg=»}
\fi
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace}

\begin{document}

Je n'ai rien à dire -- mais je le dis bien : je suis un «\,beau parleur ».

Je n'ai rien à dire -- mais je le dis bien: je suis un «beau parleur».

Je n'ai rien à dire : je suis un « beau parleur » .

Je n'ai rien à dire: je suis un «beau parleur» .

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! I was under the impression that the ``babel`` option ``\frenchbsetup{og=«, fg=»}`` required the use of ``\fg`` and ``\og``, as I had seen it used that way on stackexchange. It's great that I can type the guillemets directly! The thin non-breaking space is not an option (for reasons I explain in an edit to my question, added later). But since I have a solution, it appears, I'm happy!

Comment: Some keyboard drivers let you enter directly a thin unbreakable space…

Comment: I've opened an issue at the Polyglossia Git site: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/143

Comment: @egreg/ Thanks! I'm not very familiar with these things.

Comment: @Bernard, do you mean that there is a UTF-8 compatible character that stands in for a 'thin unbreakable space'? something like the pilcrow ``¶`` ? I try a copy-paste of it here ``  `` , from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space, is that what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: There is, and I have it on my keyboard , but it is invisible. There is a `no break space`, Unicode 00A0 (I've just used it between no and break) and a `narrow no-break space`, Unicode 202F, accessible  from a BEPO keyboard for French speaking users.

Comment: that is linked to an other bug in polyglossia : cf https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/141. Short hack to avoid it http://geekographie.maieul.net/201

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use csquotes you should make the quotes active, and input them (also the colon) without spaces as spaces can insert unwanted break points:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=14cm,paperheight=20.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}% use this font and geometry width to reproduce bad break
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote {«}{»}
\begin{document}

Je n'ai rien à dire --- mais je le dis bien: je suis un «beau parleur».

\end{document}
```

[image]